# Is boost shared_ptr <XXX> thread safe?

Tags: c++, boost, thread-safety, shared-ptr, boost-smart-ptr

I have a question about `boost::shared_ptr<T>`.

There are lots of thread.

```
using namespace boost;

class CResource
{
  // xxxxxx
}

class CResourceBase
{
public:
   void SetResource(shared_ptr<CResource> res)
   {
     m_Res = res;
   }

   shared_ptr<CResource> GetResource()
   {
      return m_Res;
   }
private:
   shared_ptr<CResource> m_Res;
}

CResourceBase base;

//----------------------------------------------
// Thread_A:
    while (true)
    {
       //...
       shared_ptr<CResource> nowResource = base.GetResource();
       nowResource.doSomeThing();
       //...
    }

// Thread_B:
    shared_ptr<CResource> nowResource;
    base.SetResource(nowResource);
    //...
```

### Q1

If **Thread_A** do not care the `nowResource` is the newest, will this part of code have problem?

I mean when **Thread_B** do not `SetResource()` completely, **Thread_A** get a wrong smart point by `GetResource()`?

### Q2

What does thread-safe mean?

If I do not care about whether the resource is newest, will the `shared_ptr<CResource> nowResource` crash the program when the `nowResource` is released or will the problem destroy the `shared_ptr<CResource>`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From the boost [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#ThreadSafety):

> `shared_ptr` objects offer the same
>   level of thread safety as built-in
>   types. A `shared_ptr` instance can be
>   "read" (accessed using only const
>   operations) simultaneously by multiple
>   threads. *Different* `shared_ptr` 
>   instances can be "written to"
>   (accessed using mutable operations
>   such as `operator=` or reset)
>   simultaneously by multiple threads
>   (even when these instances are copies,
>   and share the same reference count
>   underneath.)
>
> Any other simultaneous accesses result in undefined behavior.

So your usage is not safe, since it uses simultaneous read and write of `m_res`. *Example 3* in the boost documentation also illustrates this.

You should use a separate [mutex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_types) that guards the access to `m_res` in `SetResource`/`GetResource`.

Comment: -1 His usage does not contradict what you quoted from the boost doc. In fact, it is exactly what the boost doc says.

Comment: @ZachSaw: I expanded my answer a bit. His usage is not safe, since he does simultaneous read and write of the same `shared_ptr<>  instance.

Comment: @sth: You are right: m_res is both read and written from different threads. I had this case and without locks it crashes. It is example 3 from Thread safety section of the Boost documentation.

Answer (score 40):

`boost::shared_ptr<>` offers a certain level of thread safety.  The reference count is manipulated in a thread safe manner (unless you configure boost to disable threading support).

So you can copy a `shared_ptr` around and the ref_count is maintained correctly. What you cannot do safely in multiple threads is modify the actual `shared_ptr` object instance itself from multiple threads (such as calling `reset()` on it from multiple threads).  So your usage is not safe - you're modifying the actual `shared_ptr` instance in multiple threads - you'll need to have your own protection.

In my code, `shared_ptr`'s are generally locals or parameters passed by value, so there's no issue.  Getting them from one thread to another I generally use a thread-safe queue.

Of course none of this addresses the thread safety of accessing the object pointed to by the `shared_ptr` - that's also up to you.

Comment: No he's not modifying the shared_ptr instance in different threads! Only Thread B modifies it.

Answer (score 3):

Well, tr1::shared_ptr (which is based on boost) documentation tells a different story, which implies that resource management is thread safe, whereas access to the resource is not.

"...

Thread Safety

C++0x-only features are: rvalue-ref/move support, allocator support, aliasing constructor, make_shared & allocate_shared. Additionally, the constructors taking auto_ptr parameters are deprecated in C++0x mode.

The Thread Safety section of the Boost shared_ptr documentation says "shared_ptr objects offer the same level of thread safety as built-in types." The implementation must ensure that concurrent updates to separate shared_ptr instances are correct even when those instances share a reference count e.g.

shared_ptr a(new A);
shared_ptr b(a);

// Thread 1     // Thread 2

a.reset();      b.reset();

The dynamically-allocated object must be destroyed by exactly one of the threads. Weak references make things even more interesting. The shared state used to implement shared_ptr must be transparent to the user and invariants must be preserved at all times. The key pieces of shared state are the strong and weak reference counts. Updates to these need to be atomic and visible to all threads to ensure correct cleanup of the managed resource (which is, after all, shared_ptr's job!) On multi-processor systems memory synchronisation may be needed so that reference-count updates and the destruction of the managed resource are race-free.

..."

see 
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/memory.html#std.util.memory.shared_ptr

Comment: "Well, tr1::shared_ptr (which is based on boost) documentation tells a different story, which implies that resource management is thread safe, whereas access to the resource is not." Well I tend to agree with this, because the most that it can guarantee a shared_ptr is that reference count to the resource is maintained consistently in the presence of threads. The actual resource it is pointing to must be thread safe on it's own in case you mutate the resource value.

Answer (score 1):

**m_Res** is not threadsafe ,because it simultaneous read/write,
you need boost::atomic_store/load function to protects it.

```
//--- Example 3 ---
// thread A
p = p3; // reads p3, writes p
// thread B
p3.reset(); // writes p3; undefined, simultaneous read/write
```

Answer (score -1):

Add, your class has a Cyclic-references condition; the `shared_ptr<CResource> m_Res` can't be a member of `CResourceBase`.  You can use `weak_ptr` instead.

Comment: "_shared_ptr<CResource> m_Res can't be a member of CResourceBase_" why not?