# destructor is never called

Tags: c++

sorry for my inattension, in short the `~CSArray()` is work, but interface and implementation of the class there was in different files, so mistake is here

Comment: Are you sure the retain/release counts match?

Comment: Does the retain count actually reach zero? Is the destructor of `CSObject` invoked? Is the destructor of `CSObject` virtual?

Comment: from debugger,
'Does the retain count actually reach zero?' yes
  
'Is the destructor of CSObject invoked?' yes  

'Is the destructor of CSObject virtual?' yes  
  
destructor of CSArray is not invoked

Comment: You know the best way to get a good answer is to post compilable code that reproduces the error. But lacking that it looks like either destructor of CSObject is not virtual or self is not pointing at the correct thing (what is self?).

Comment: Could we see the declaration and definition of the destructor of `CSObject`? My money is still on that not being virtual. Also, you changed `delete this` to `delete self`. What is `self`?

Answer (score 4):

Be sure that you declared your destructor `virtual` in the base class.

Comment: `virtual`, CSObject destuctor is invoked only,

Answer (score 2):

The shown code is currently too short to see the problem.

Some good advice: Never ever build your own reference-counting scheme. Use proven library-implementations like std::auto_ptr, boost::shared_ptr, or boost::shared_array and take advantage of RAII (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII). 
Also, avoid "delete this" like the plague. It may seem to work in some cases, but generally the pre/postconditions are too much.

Comment: Studying the conditions on `delete this;` is a good idea before attempting reference counting, but reference-counting is neither complicated nor difficult, as evidenced by the HUGE number of COM components, all of which implement `IUnknown`.  Also, the classes you suggest aren't thread-safe, so "reuse the library version" could make a lot of trouble.

Comment: @Ben: And OP's code is thread-safe? Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/692438/is-boost-shared-ptr-xxx-thread-safe

Comment: Markus, I like Cocoa style in, so I make them

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `_retainCount = 0`

It works, provided you have declared your destructor `virtual` in base class.

See below code: (gcc version 3.4.3)

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
        A(){cout<<"A ctor"<<endl;};
        virtual ~A(){cout<<"A dtor"<<endl;};
        void testDel()
        {
            delete this;
        }
};

class B: public A
{
    public:
        B(){cout<<"B ctor"<<endl;};
        ~B(){cout<<"B dtor"<<endl;};
};

int main()
{
    B bObj;

    bObj.testDel(); 
   return 0; 
}
```

Result: w/o explicit delete

```
A ctor
B ctor
B dtor
A dtor
```

Result: with explicit delete

```
A ctor
B ctor
B dtor
A dtor
B dtor
A dtor
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "works perfectly"; deleting an automatic variable gives undefined behaviour, and is as likely to crash as to give the double-destruction you got.

Comment: @Mike Seymour I was just to demonstrate that the destructor is called. Well I should remove word "perfectly" :) ... I didn't consider for UB here ...